# return object value with space in key

Tags: php, mysql, object, whitespace

just come across something I've never came across before. 
I have a value in my table `"Device Vendor"` and i am returning the data os an object.

usually I would call `$ob->var_name` but obviously `$ob->Device Vendor` will not work.

How do I return the value?

Regards

Comment: did  u try $ob->'Device Vendor'

Comment: not sure, but have you tried `$obj->'Device Vendor'`?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You use the following syntax

```
 $ob->{'Device Vendor'}
```

Answer (score 16):

The syntax is this:

```
$ob->{'Device Vendor'}
```

I'm having a hard time trying to find an explicit reference to this in the PHP manual. I'm afraid that it needs to be inferred and you can only do so if you already know the answer. At [Classes and Objects-> Properties](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) they say:

> Class member variables are called "properties". [...] They are defined
> by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed
> by a normal variable declaration.

The rules that applies now is [Variable variables](http://es.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

> In order to use variable variables with arrays, you have to resolve an
> ambiguity problem. That is, if you write `$$a[1]` then the parser needs
> to know if you meant to use `$a[1]` as a variable, or if you wanted `$$a`
> as the variable and then the `[1]` index from that variable. The syntax
> for resolving this ambiguity is: `${$a[1]}` for the first case and
> `${$a}[1]` for the second.

We are basically "abusing" variable variables so we can use a space.