# Defining class variables with a space

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a class which has object names with a space in between. Just so I can access them like this:

```
$object->{'Var name with spaces'};
```

I've read [this topic over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649410/mysql-php-return-object-value-with-space-in-key) and now know how to access those variables, but I'm not sure how to create a class with these variables. I've tried something like this, but I can't get it to work:

```
class Hotel
{
    public ${'Var name with spaces'} = 'Some value'; // Fails
}
```

How would I go and create variables in a class definition containing spaces?

Comment: Do you _really need_ spaces in your class properties? Spaces are a presentation element.

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want to do this?

Comment: You really shouldn't. If you want to assign multiple properties to a variable (a name and some value for your example), just use an array for the value.

Comment: When you say "fails", do you mean you get an error on that line?

Comment: If this is theoretical, it's a great question. If you're going to use this naming convention for something that someone's paying for, please, oh please, **don't**.

Comment: As nickb has done below... but it should be avoided it will just lead to problems... I echo the question above, why do you require this?

Comment: just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you should. Don't do this. Just don't. Please...

Comment: Haha, I __love__ the emotional response! :) Don't worry, no blood will be shed, it was purely a theorerical question! A friend and I were talking and got into a discussion about whether this was possible, so I decided to give it a go!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you'd have to do this in your constructor, because class properties cannot require runtime evaluation.

```
class Hotel {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->{'Var name with spaces'} = 'Some value';
    }
}
```

You can see it working in [this demo](http://viper-7.com/MzBxUc), but I think the comments have shed enough light on why you shouldn't do this. `:)`

Comment: @Andorenan You can name variables like this, but seriously, variables with spaces in the are a pain in the ass, terrible and your code will need to cater for them left, right and center because you can't just use them as variables. Don't do it. +1 for correct (but ghastly and makes me shiver thinking that this will end up in code) answer.